# if any checkbox is checked, slide down a div, and vice versa

Tags: jquery, checkbox, slidetoggle

I have a little PM function on my website. I want the users to be able to delete the messages.
I also have jQuery script that shows what function you maybe want to do (delete, archive, and that stuff) when you check a checkbox.

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? '400' : '200';
    $('#functions').slideToggle(c);
});
```

I took it from another question here on stackoverflow. But now, if i have many messages, then I'll have as many checkboxes. If I check the first, the functions are showed. But when I check the second one, it slides up again. So I can't use slideToggle(), and I can't think of any other way to do it.

What I'm trying to do is to slide down (show) the functions if you check some checkboxes, then when you uncheck them, it should slide up again

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like:

```
$('.checkbox').filter(":checked").length ? 
     $('#functions').slideDown() : $('#functions').slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

using `slideUp` and `slideDown`
try this

```
 $('.checkbox').change(function(){
   if(this.checked){
      $('#functions').slideDown(400)
   }else{
      $('#functions').slideUp(200)
   }

});
```

Comment: that works if you check them all, but as soon as you uncheck one, it slides up...

Comment: do you have seperate functions div for seperate checkbox??

Answer (score 0):

Try using animate:

```
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#functions").animate({"width":"400px"});
        } else {
            $("#functions").animate({"width":"300px"});
        }
    });
});
```

See this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nthef/16/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:  http://jsfiddle.net/e4Gjj/2/

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    var idx = $(this).index()-1;
    $('div.functions').children('div').eq(idx).slideToggle(400);  
});
```

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't think you'd need the html. The functions div is above all messages, and then all checkboxes are listed below.

Comment: if you can paste the corresponding html or fiddle would be even better.